# Storing session data in Silverlight 4 - that will hang around till the Browser closes

Tags: cookies, silverlight-4.0, session-variables, browser-cache

I am wondering if it is possible to store an object, example being a UserName or User Context somewhere in the ASP.NET Serverside, that can be reused each time the browser is refreshed.

I have a User object which i can seralize, and want to be able to store this in the ASP.NET or Broweser session, so that if the user refreshes the page, it will automatically grab these details and log the user in.

I cant seem to find a way to do this currently, and am thinking that maybe i can only do it through using a silverlight cache tool or something.

Also if i am able to store this object in the session, is it only viewable to that one browser or is it viewable to all instances of the appliation on the Server.

Thanks for your help with this.

Cheers Robbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is data that you really need to protect from end user tampering, just stick it in a cookie.  http://yinyangme.com/blog/post/Cookies-for-Silverlight.aspx